# apache http reverse proxy, can it be used to inspect the payload

Tags: apache

I am currently working on a very old system, which has a apache http reverse proxy set up in front of its main server - forwarding requests.

Is it possible to inspect requests in apache and re-route based on payload content? I have been searching for this for a while and cannot find anything or examples?

maybea custom module?

Comment: payload as in request's body? the posted stuff not only the urls or headers? if its so, what you are looking maybe not a load balancer but a deep packet inspection stuff.

Comment: @BagusTesa Yes as in the request body. But the Apache has already been setup and in place. I wanted to know if it was possible.